# The repository 'https://ppa.launchpadcontent.net/tuxinvader/jammy-mainline/ubuntu jammy InRelease' is not signed

Tags: apt, kernel, updates, ppa, repository

I tried to install 6.0 kernel and I just blindly followed the tutorial, so I broke my system and it now every time I try to update it shows me this error

```
W: GPG error: https://ppa.launchpadcontent.net/tuxinvader/jammy-mainline/ubuntu jammy InRelease: The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY 3844A6C1C6FD1056
E: The repository 'https://ppa.launchpadcontent.net/tuxinvader/jammy-mainline/ubuntu jammy InRelease' is not signed.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
```

Comment: Remove that PPA entry from the sources list file.

Comment: can you help me do that I tried --remove and ppa-purge  I dont know what to do

Comment: https://www.addictivetips.com/ubuntu-linux-tips/ubuntu-sources-list-editing-guide/#:~:text=To%20start%2C%20open%20up%20your,by%20using%20the%20command%20below.&text=Once%20inside%20of%20the%20Nano,changes%20to%20Ubuntu%20with%20update. Follow the disabling section.

Comment: sudo apt-key adv --keyserver keyserver.ubuntu.com 3844A6C1C6FD1056 && sudot update
[sudo] password for marko:           
Executing: /tmp/apt-key-gpghome.c7lyXUVHCe/gpg.1.sh --keyserver keyserver.ubuntu.com 3844A6C1C6FD1056
gpg: WARNING: no command supplied.  Trying to guess what you mean ...
gpg: can't open '3844A6C1C6FD1056' it didn't work

Comment: I dont see it in /etc/apt/sources.list

Comment: It has to be there.

Comment: @nb52er As `apt-key` is deprecated and on the way out, I wouldn't advise new users to use it. If the OP wanted to keep the repository, they could [add a keyring](https://itsfoss.com/apt-key-deprecated/) for example in `/usr/share/keyrings/` and have the repository refer to that. But as far as I understand, the OP just wants to get rid of the repo.

Comment: deb mirror://mirrors.ubuntu.com/mirrors.txt focal main restricted universe multiverse
deb-src mirror://mirrors.ubuntu.com/mirrors.txt focal main restricted universe multiverse
deb mirror://mirrors.ubuntu.com/mirrors.txt focal-updates main restricted universe multiverse
deb-src mirror://mirrors.ubuntu.com/mirrors.txt focal-updates main restricted universe multiverse is in there

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look for the entry for this repository in the directory `/etc/apt`. Maybe it was added to the main source file `/etc/apt/sources`, maybe it was added as an individual file in the directory `/etc/apt/sources.d`. The entry should look similar to

```
deb https://ppa.launchpadcontent.net/tuxinvader/jammy-mainline/ubuntu jammy main 
deb-src https://ppa.launchpadcontent.net/tuxinvader/jammy-mainline/ubuntu jammy main
```

Remove those lines and reload your local package information with `apt update`.

Comment: I just see deb mirror://mirrors.ubuntu.com/mirrors.txt focal main restricted universe multiverse
deb-src mirror://mirrors.ubuntu.com/mirrors.txt focal main restricted universe multiverse
deb mirror://mirrors.ubuntu.com/mirrors.txt focal-updates main restricted universe multiverse
deb-src mirror://mirrors.ubuntu.com/mirrors.txt focal-updates main restricted universe multiverse

Comment: @jifitailu The entry could be in the main list `/etc/apt/sources`, or in a separate file in the directory `/etc/apt/sources.list.d`. Please look in both places.

Comment: I see two files named like repo  do I just delete them?

Comment: deleting them did the trick thank you!